# Custom Caption Buttons in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I am creating a custom window style in WPF. So far, I have been able to accomplish something that almost works, in pure XAML.

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
    <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
        <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
        <Border Height="40" Padding="5" DockPanel.Dock="Top" BorderBrush="#7FA0A0A0" 
            BorderThickness="0,0,0,1">
            <Grid WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome="True">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                <Image Source="Resources/Logo/f-dark.png" />
                <TextBlock Margin="0,0,0,0" Text="{TemplateBinding Title}" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                FontSize="16" Foreground="#AF000000"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                    WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome="True" Background="Transparent">
                <Button Width="{x:Static SystemParameters.WindowCaptionButtonWidth}"
                    Command="{x:Static SystemCommands.MinimizeWindowCommand}"
                    Style="{StaticResource LinkButton}"
                    WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome="True"
                    IsEnabled="True">
                <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource Icon}" FontSize="18">&#xE15B;</TextBlock>
                </Button>
                <Button Width="{x:Static SystemParameters.WindowCaptionButtonWidth}"
                    Command="{x:Static SystemCommands.RestoreWindowCommand}"
                    Style="{StaticResource LinkButton}"
                    WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome="True"
                    IsEnabled="True">
                <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource Icon}" FontSize="18">&#xE5D0;</TextBlock>
                </Button>
                <Button Width="{x:Static SystemParameters.WindowCaptionButtonWidth}"
                    Command="{x:Static SystemCommands.CloseWindowCommand}"
                    Style="{StaticResource LinkButton}"
                    WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome="True"
                    IsEnabled="True">
                <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource Icon}" FontSize="18">&#xE5CD;</TextBlock>
                </Button>
            </StackPanel>
            </Grid>

        </Border>
        <Border>
            <ContentPresenter/>
        </Border>

        </DockPanel>
    </Border>
</ControlTemplate>
```

However, the in the window chrome buttons do not highlight or change the cursor (and buttons with the same style behave as intended). Clicking on them has no effect. Why is this? How do I get the buttons to be interactive?

When I first open the window, I get something like this:
[image: an example window]

I would also like to be able to fix the black border, but my main problem is the fact that the caption buttons are noninteractive.

Answer (score 2):

I have solved both problems. It turns out that the `SystemCommands` do not have implementations, and instead are just `RoutedCommand`s. (why did they do that?)

So, I made an attached property that sets the `CommandBindings` for each window that I apply this style to.

```
public class Helper
{
    public static bool GetUseWindowCommandBindings(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (bool)obj.GetValue(UseWindowCommandBindingsProperty);
    }

    public static void SetUseWindowCommandBindings(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(UseWindowCommandBindingsProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty UseWindowCommandBindingsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("UseWindowCommandBindings", typeof(bool), typeof(Helper), new PropertyMetadata(false, UseWindowCommandBindingsChanged));

    private static void UseWindowCommandBindingsChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs dpce)
    {
        if (d is Window w && dpce.NewValue is bool b && b)
        {
            w.CommandBindings.Add(
                new CommandBinding(
                    SystemCommands.MinimizeWindowCommand,
                    (s, e) => SystemCommands.MinimizeWindow(w),
                    (s, e) => e.CanExecute = true
                    ));
            w.CommandBindings.Add(
                new CommandBinding(
                    SystemCommands.RestoreWindowCommand,
                    (s, e) => SystemCommands.RestoreWindow(w),
                    (s, e) => e.CanExecute = true
                    ));
            w.CommandBindings.Add(
                new CommandBinding(
                    SystemCommands.MaximizeWindowCommand,
                    (s, e) => SystemCommands.MaximizeWindow(w),
                    (s, e) => e.CanExecute = true
                    ));
            w.CommandBindings.Add(
                new CommandBinding(
                    SystemCommands.CloseWindowCommand,
                    (s, e) => SystemCommands.CloseWindow(w),
                    (s, e) => e.CanExecute = true
                    ));
        }
    }
}
```

I had to put the attachment of the `CommandBindings` in the property-change handler since WPF calls `SetValue()` directly. Now, in my style, I added the line:

```
<Setter Property="view:Helper.UseWindowCommandBindings" Value="True" />
```

Now the buttons work as expected. To fix the black border, I set the width of the outermost `Border` in my template to `{TemplateBinding Width}`. But this creates the problem of having a massive, all-around black border if I maximize the window:
[image]